# Fiware CEP Sending Output Events to the Context Broker with Fiware-Service and Fiware-ServicePath

Tags: fiware, complex-event-processing

I'm trying to send an event to a consumer, in order to modify one attribute on an entity of the Context Broker.

The issue is, that I've got the entity that is going to receive the derivation event, under a Fiware-Service and Fiware-ServicePath.

I don't know where to place that information. I found no information on any of the documents (not even in user guide nor programmer guide).

Where should I place Fiware-Service and Fiware-ServicePath to be part of the header of the REST call?

Comment: Does Fiware-Service and Fiware-ServicePath refer to the ContextBroker URL?

Comment: I mean to the header of the HTTP request that the CEP should send to the Context Broker. Initially, both Fiware-Service and Fiware-ServicePath, as far as I know, are informed in the HEADER of the request.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the feature of CEP to add headers to meet options in Orion has been created, but exact schedule for implementation not finalized yet.

Comment: We apreciate the information. When you have more details about de schedule, will be fantastic to know about it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, CEP does not support this feature presently.

Comment: Do you mean that using CEP it is not possible to establish the context broker as a consumer, sending to the context broker events addressed to a specific Fiware-Service?

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer. Regarding to the issue, is this feature on your roadmap? and if it's, with what priority? We're thinking in adding one CEP module in our Fiware environment, and for us, it's an important issue. We just need some information in order to take decisions.